# Informal Suffix Usage: -ity/ety

Tags: word-usage, terminology, formality, suffixes, present-progressive

Sometimes in very informal or comic book language one will see phrases such as "bonkity bonk", "flippity-flop", and "knockity knock". Other examples include "crunchity", "swirlity", etc, etc.

I have heard people add the suffix "-ity" to a number of verbs and it always seems to imply a progressive action. For example, "knockity knock" can be used to refer to the action of knocking on a door while it is still happening.

This suffix is different than "-ing" which also shows present progression. It wouldn't sound right to say "knocking knock" or "bonking bonk".

But what IS the difference? And what is the correct term for this suffix?

Comment: Quite often also spelled "-ety", as in _blankety-blank,_ a euphemism for some (any, really) [taboo term](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html); it's one aural equivalent of "%!#*$" in a speech balloon. The reason the suffix is there is strictly for sound -- this is onomatopoeic, imitating rhythmic sounds, and the suffix gives a pattern ***da** da da **da*** which occurs often in nature and in human communication, from knocking on doors to speaking English to Beethoven's Fifth Symphony to Morse Code.

Comment: Good points. So for single words ("bonkity", "blankety", "knockity") perhaps these would count as interjections rather than as progressive actions...? While onomatopoeia makes sense, it still seems as if there is a degree to which the suffix functions as an indicator of progression, rather than for ease of speech alone.

Comment: Onomatopoeic speech is iconic. The best symbol for anything is the thing itself; the best aural signal of progression is a progression of sounds.

Comment: I guess it could be labeled an "onomatopoeic progressive suffix" or the "onomatopoeic progressive tense"... to be unnecessarily technical. :)

Comment: Oh, no. Progressive is not a tense, and this suffix is not part of grammar, and certainly doesn't mean the same thing as the English progressive. It doesn't **mean** anything, any more than _mmm-hmm_ does, and doesn't need a separate name, certainly not one confusing it with real grammar.

Comment: I stand corrected on the usage of "progressive tense". It's an aspect, though often referred to as a tense. But I do disagree when it comes to it not being a part of grammar. The fact is that it is used in a range of speech contexts with a fairly consistent "meaning" as far as the indication of progression. I would also argue that "mmm-hmm" is a part of grammar for which we currently may not have a suitable grammatical category. But that's just my opinion, I guess. I'll stop here. :)

Comment: The English progressive construction is certainly part of grammar. But **this** /-əɾi/ form is not the progressive construction, and is not part of grammar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-ity), the suffix *-ity* indicates a state or condition.  There are plenty of "formal" words having this suffix also:

- angularity
- density
- eternity
- fidelity

(And that is just a sampling of the more common words I found in a search, stopping at f).

So, it seems the intent of *knockity* is to indicate the state of being knocked.  As you suggest, to show that the action is currently taking place.

Comment: True! And so added to a verb rather than a subject would categorize this suffix as... what? If it is used as a present progressive suffix, perhaps John Lawler is correct in pointing to onomatopoeia as the reason -ity/-ety is used versus -ing.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of reduplication, wherein the word is repeated and often modified slightly.  It is quite common and found in such phrases as *super-duper* and *willy-nilly*, the latter of which originated in the phrase *will he, nill he?* 'does he want to or does he not?'.

I do not believe that there is any term in particular for using *-ity*, however.  Any similarity between the suffix *-ity* in *knockity-knock* and that in such words as *normality, ability, &c.* is most likely coincidental.

Whereas other forms of reduplication undergo no change, such as *bye-bye* and *night-night*, some undergo a change in the stem, such as *criss-cross* and *knick-knack*, and yet others change both the stem and add an affix, such as *kitty-cat* and *fancy-shmancy*.

Answer (score 1):

[*Bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bippity_Boppity_Boo) (also called "The Magic Song"[1]) is a novelty song introduced in the 1950 film Cinderella. It is pronounced more often as **Bippity Boppity Boo**.  They are nonsense magic words, probably based on *itty bitty*, a kind of baby talk for *small* The phrase **Bibbidi-bobbidi-boo** goes back at least to the story "Bubnoff and the Devil" by Ivan Turgenev (1818-1883)

[**itty**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=itty-bitty) is first recorded in 1798, in a letter of Jane Austen, and is a baby-talk form of little. **itty-bitty** is first recorded in 1855.

Adding **itty**, as in *knockitty-knock* is just being nonsensical, jovial in a childish way.

NB: This does not apply to *nitty-gritty*, which has a very unsavory origin, and maintains it's scandalous overtones.

Comment: This is a good point. This may very well be the historical root of the suffix.